Can the signing of a bill by an acting governor be overturned by the actual governor?
In this article, it indicates that a bill was passed by the NJ State Assembly and signed into law by the Acting Governor who was the Senate President per the NJ's succession rules. This seemed odd to me, so I also verified that this was the case on Wikipedia, where I learned the Acting Governor signed 3 other bills as well.
The need for an Acting Governor in this case was simply because both the Governor and Lt. Governor were out of state.
For the purposes of this question, let's assume that the Senate President and the Governor are not in agreement on these bills. Could the Senate President, serving as an Acting Governor, sign a bill into law without the approval of the actual Governor if the latter is merely out of state? If so, can the actual Governor reverse the signing once they return to the state?
If not, is the validity of the law subject to judicial scrutiny if it only passed because of the Senate President's vote? In other words, is there some sort of requirement that a bill can't become a law if the person signing it also voted for it? I ask this because given the Senate President's role, it seems they could create scenarios where laws they want are passed expressly when the Governor and Lt. Governor are out of town, thereby ensuring they can quickly sign them before the Governor returns to veto.

Interesting question. I feel like a legislature could really wreak havok if an opposing-party governor wanted to try to run for president. Rally in Florida? We'll enact gun-control while you're gone. Fundraiser in L.A.? Be ready to enforce our fetal-personhood law when you get back.

@bdb484 maybe not that easy as the post of Lt. Governor would need to also be vacant, but on the same note, NJ's previous Lt. Governor did pass away and the current one is being tapped to replace Bob Menendez in the Senate...ok maybe this is easier than I thought.

FYI, in the case of federal laws there are ways for POTUS to sign them while out of the country if it's urgent. See https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/73239/how-often-do-us-presidents-sign-laws-while-abroad

@Barmar AFAIK POTUS being absent from the country doesn't render the position vacant.


Can the signing of a bill by an acting governor be overturned by the
actual governor?

No.

is there some sort of requirement that a bill can't become a law if
the person signing it also voted for it?

No.
See New Jersey's state constitution, especially, Article V, Section 1, paragraphs 6, 7, and 14. Paragraphs 6 & 7 discuss governorship vacancies and has none of the qualifications suggested in the question. Paragraph 14 discusses how a bill is signed into law and likewise contains none of the qualifications suggested in the question.
The key point is that there is nothing in the New Jersey Constitution, and in particular, in the relevant paragraphs of the New Jersey Constitution, that limits the authority of an acting governor to act by signing bills passed by the New Jersey state legislature.
